# Does strict quasiconvexity imply continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

Strict quasiconvexity definition:

$f(tx + (1-t)y) < \max \{f(x), f(y)\}$ for any $x,y$ in the domain and $t \in (0,1)$

Comment: What if $f$ is strictly increasing and has a jump discontinuity?

Comment: That is what I am concerned about. However,here:https://503d7d0c-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/petetroyan/home/useful_math_for_microeconomists.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crvPo4DtU569E94f0XDdEGEKl3K8aqciRxfQ_gcAeXMo8ndI4xXlS-C_uoPfQdDsreTacvLZXJOvSOw-q_n0o5QZNfF_eWUUv5sfcSNyphAbER0LQ6lKe_NI80eRY1-xCW2MrmJCZQs72xEEtE2VGD4nrmfpGdftUUrmL-_GSZ4LLBt0B4MXvf_1Xpt25rXnLN6HZ9OxBGyXdvybK1U06Y36D3VhC5GcKBQdHqFgHs1vHSU9lvB9_uxA4o-kH8d1nOkvpac&attredirects=0 in the proof of Theorem 8, I don't see how strict quasiconvexity in constraints implies the result, unless strict quasiconvexity implies continuity

Comment: What if $f(x)=1$ for all $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 8 of the document mentioned in the comment is not true.

Consider
$$f(x) = -(x-1)^2, \qquad g_1(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if } x = 0, \\ |x| & \text{if } x \ne 0. \end{cases}$$
Then, $f$ is strictly concave and $g_1$ is strictly quasi-convex. Moreover, $x^* = 0$ is the unique solution of
$$\text{Maximize}\; f(x) \quad \text{subject to } g_1(x) \le 0$$
and the constraint is non-binding.
However, $\hat x = 1$ is the unique solution of the relaxed problem
$$\text{Maximize}\; f(x).$$